# Derive Factor in Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

First of all sorry for my stupidity. I am learning to find Fourier Series coefficient as fast a possible for my exam. But it's getting really confusing deriving a factor.

For example:
In one website, I see the formula derived for $a_0$:

[Derived Formula 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10nrQ.png)

On the other hand, I see the formula derived for $a_0$:

[Derived Formula 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLDmk.png)

Where both function are of the period $2\pi$ and on interval $\left\[-\pi, \pi\right\]$.

It would be really appreciable, if somebody would explain me how the factor in one formula is $1/\pi$ and $1/2\pi$ in another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially they are both equivalent. It's just that some literature defines a Fourier series $S(x)$ by

$$S(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+...$$

and other literature defines it as$$S(x)=a_0+...$$

Comment: Thank you so much... Is it possible to explain me here, how can I find this factor accurately? If not, can you give me a good reference to look at.

Comment: Just make a choice on how you define a Fourier series and use the relevant formula. If you use the first expression that I put then use the picture associated with "Derived Formula 2" and if you choose the second expression then use the picture associated with "Derived Formula 1".